# While uploading photo on website it is not storing in specified folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, image-uploading

I am trying to store an image on specified folder when it is uploaded.I am not getting where I am doing mistake.

Here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var search = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmpID  == SessionWrapper.UserId);
        if (search != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Email you've enter is used by someone else. Reenter please";
        }
        else
        {
            Login login = new Login
            {
                UserEmail = model.UserEmail,
                UserPass = Crypto.HashPassword(model.UserPass),
                RoleID = 2,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
            };
            db.Logins.Add(login);

            db.SaveChanges();

            if (photo != null)
            {
                photo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Photo/" + SessionWrapper.UserId + ".png"));
            }
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And this is my View Page

```
    @model DivineDemo.Models.EmployeeViewModel
    @using DivineDemo.Models



@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<p class="alert-success">@ViewBag.Message</p>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
      <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="photo" />

                <button>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                    Submit your registration details
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
}
</div>
```

I have created folder named 'Photo' to store this uploaded images but it is not storing.
I am using Asp.Net MVC with database first Entity Framework..

Comment: Would you please provide some code?

Comment: Please debug the code and check what is  the exact path returned by Server.MapPath and try to match your desired path with it